# getting empty body for GET type rest api in wso2 api manager's custom handler

Tags: wso2-api-manager

My response payload inside the soap body is empty.Below is the custom handler code which is configured in api manager. I printed the body, it displays empty.My rest api should return list of data.

```
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext)
 {
try {

            RelayUtils.buildMessage(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 log.info("Response Body:"+messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody());
}
```

Its working if API's response status is OK but in case of ACCEPT status, response body is empty.

```
This is my logs after enabling the wire. Please help. Thanks in advance.

    In Case of @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK) wire log
=================================================================
"GET /customer/list HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,643] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,643] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Postman-Token: 780f0eac-254b-d93e-9801-93fe8bac79a6[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: localhost:8088[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,644] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,646] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,646] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,646] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,646] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,646] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 08:18:58 GMT[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,647] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,647] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "5a[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,647] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[{"id":"1","name":"abc"},{"id":"2","name":"bcd"},{"id":"3","name":"cde"}]"    
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,652] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,652] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "0[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,652] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,700]  INFO - MessageBuilderHandler Response body:   `<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <jsonArray><?xml-multiple  jsonElement?>
<jsonElement>
<id>1</id>
<name>abc</name>
</jsonElement>
<jsonElement><id>2</id>
<name>bcd</name>
</jsonElement>
<jsonElement>
<id>3</id>
<name>cde</name>
</jsonElement>
</jsonArray>
</soapenv:Body> `   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,868] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 08:18:58 GMT[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,869] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,870] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,870] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "54[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,870] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[
{"id":1,"name":"abc"}, 
{"id":2,"name":"bcd"},
{"id":3,"name":"cde"}
][\r][\n]"
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,870] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "0[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:48:58,870] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"     


In Case of @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.ACCEPTED) wire log
===================================================================

DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "GET /GetCustomerList/1.0.0/customer/list HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Host: localhost:8243[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Authorization: Bearer 93cdc897-f75b-351e-ab4e-e4bd347bc742[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36[\r][\n]"   
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Postman-Token: 6c341e45-3d95-10af-d3b8-1e1f25360d18[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,060] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,061] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,061] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,061] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,070]  INFO - MessageBuilderHandler Reqest body:
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,081] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "GET /customer/list HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,082] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,082] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,082] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Postman-Token: 6c341e45-3d95-10af-d3b8-1e1f25360d18[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,082] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,083] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,083] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Host: localhost:8088[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,083] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,083] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" 
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,083] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,309] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,309] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,309] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,310] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,310] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 08:22:37 GMT[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,310] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,311] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "5a[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,311] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[{"id":"1","name":"abc"},{"id":"2","name":"bcd"},{"id":"3","name":"cde"}][\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,312] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "0[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,312] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,317]  INFO - MessageBuilderHandler Response body:`<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>`  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,320] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,321] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,321] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,321] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,321] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,321] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 08:22:37 GMT[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,322] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,322] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,322] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,322] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "0[\r][\n]"  
[2016-10-07 13:52:37,322] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question,you are saying the response body is empty when backend responds with 202 code and when backend response code is 200,you could access the backend response from above code logic. First you'll have to check actually a response body is coming from backend when the http code is 202.For that you could enable wire logs as in [1] for wso2 apimanager and check the back-end response.

[1] http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: I have added wire logs . Please check.Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the apim version  you are using, I did check with apim 2.0.0 and found no issue. Can you remove your custom handler and check whether response comes to client when code is 202? Thus you can isolate the issue if it is coming from you custom handler